# Convert Redis DEL to UNLINK command

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Recently we had an engineer who made some modification to our Redis server that automatically converted DEL commands into UNLINK commands even though our apps were firing DEL commands at it. The server has since been replaced and the engineer no longer with us. Does anyone know how to setup redis server to do this conversion automatically like this? I'm finding nothing online about it.

And a related question if that solution does not exist is how do you perform a UNLINK using StackExchange.Redis client?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WRT the 1st question - most probably that engineer had set the 'lazyfree-lazy-server-del' configuration directive to 'yes'. You can find all the information about this behavior (lazy-free) in the [redis.conf](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf) file.

WRT 2nd q - sorry, IDK.

Answer (score 1):

[rename-command](https://redis.io/topics/security#disabling-of-specific-commands) can be an option here.

```
rename-command DEL UNLINK
```

You can add the above line in Redis configuration file (`redis.conf`) and restart the Redis server.